# Reverse order of LinkedHashMap to LinkedHashMap or ArrayList

Tags: java, android, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I have a `LinkedHashMap<String,String>` which looks something like this (don't really know how to illustrate a HashMap):

```
{
  "10/10/2010 10:10:10" => "SomeText1",
  "10/10/2019 10:10:19" => "SomeText2",
  "10/10/2020 10:10:20" => "SomeText3",
  "10/10/2021 10:10:21" => "SomeText4"
}
```

And I want to put it like this:

```
{
  "10/10/2021 10:10:21" => "SomeText4",
  "10/10/2020 10:10:20" => "SomeText3",
  "10/10/2019 10:10:19" => "SomeText2",
  "10/10/2010 10:10:10" => "SomeText1"
}
```

I have written this solution which works because the result I want is an ArrayList, but i was thinking if there was an easier way to reverse the LinkedHashMap maintaining the same type using a tool like **sort** for example.

```
private LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
int sizeOfHashMap = map.size();
ArrayList reversedHashToArrayList = new ArrayList(map.size());
   for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
   String key = entry.getKey();
   String value = entry.getValue();

   reversedHashToArrayList.add(0,entry);
}
```

Comment: Do you actually need the reversed `LinkedHashMap`? Wouldn't it be simpler to just iterate over it in reverse order where needed?

Comment: Any map is non-ordered structure. You can't expect **any** order from the map. It's only purpose is to store key-value pairs. The order of keys in a set can easily change in runtime, and you should never expect any order from the map

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko well that's exactly why you use a `LinkedHashMap` which has a predictable iteration order...

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko That's why I used a LinkedHasMap as Ben explained it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A LinkedHashMap orders by insertion; it would be more logical to sort on the associated date time:

```
private SortedMap<LocalDateTime, String> map = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.naturalOrder()
                                                                       .reversed());

LocalDateTimeFormatter formatter = LocalDateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu HH:mm:ss");
map.put(LocalDateTime.parse("10/10/2010 10:10:10", formatter), "...");
```

To specify that the map is sorted, there is the interface SortedMap. Better use an interface, which is more versatile. The implementation class for a sorted map is the TreeMap. However you want a reversed comparison.

You could use a Local specific pattern. Mind that above I chose Month/Day and not the British Day/Month.

Answer (score 1):

If your motive is just to reverse the map ( show in descending order ) you can use 
**Java.util.TreeMap.descendingMap() :**  It returns a reverse order view of the mappings contained in the map`

```
LinkedHashMap<String,String> map = .... //this is your intial hashmap
TreeMap<String,String> tmap = new TreeMap<>(map);
map.clear();
map.putAll(tmap.descendingMap());
```

*This will do the trick.*

Answer (score 0):

Here Is My Own Written Logic for you. without using any built in functions to reverse:

```
 LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("10/10/2010 10:10:10", "SomeText1");
    map.put("10/10/2019 10:10:19", "SomeText2");
    map.put("10/10/2020 10:10:20", "SomeText3");
    map.put("10/10/2021 10:10:21", "SomeText4");

    LinkedHashMap<String, String> reversed = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    String[] keys = map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.size()]);

    for (int i = keys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reversed.put(keys[i], map.get(keys[i]));
    }
```

Comment: Why not store in `String[]` it would avoid the bad `toString()`

Comment: Also using `get(i)` on any `Linked` map or list is generally something you want to avoid... This could be massively improved in many ways. You could use an iterator for starters

Comment: You can simply do `System.out.println(reversed)` and paste the result instead of a picture, if would be better

Comment: We are not downvoting, others do, please take in consideration our comment to improve your post (and your lvl)

Comment: It's a quite terribly inefficient solution, which is probably why it's receiving downvotes.

Comment: Seriously ? Did you not read the first part of my comment : 'I did not downvote' so please be kind, we give improvements

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using a `LinkedHashMap` reversing it while keeping it somewhat efficient is not as easy. This is a solution that reverses a given `LinkedHashMap` using the iterator order (which is predictable for a `LinkedHashMap` and therefore probably what you are looking for).

Note that other solutions like using a `SortedMap` or a `TreeMap` are probably still better. Yet, for the sake of sticking to your original question, here is a solution:

```
public static <K, V> LinkedHashMap<K, V> reverse(LinkedHashMap<K, V> map)
{
    LinkedHashMap<K, V> reversedMap = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();

    ListIterator<Entry<K, V>> it = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet()).listIterator(map.entrySet().size());

    while (it.hasPrevious())
    {
        Entry<K, V> el = it.previous();
        reversedMap.put(el.getKey(), el.getValue());
    }

    return reversedMap;
}
```

Note that you won't get around wrapping the entry set into an `ArrayList` sadly as only that provides you with an `ListIterator` which can be initialized to any point other than the first element. Having something like a `reverseIterator()` method would simplify life a lot - sadly there is none available.

Complexity wise you iterate the list twice with this approach, first for the `listIterator` call from start to the last element and then once more from the back to the front when using `previous`. So you are looking at **O(2n)** here.

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 21, the [`reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#reversed()) method on `LinkedHashMap` can be used to a reversed view of the map.

```java
LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = ...;
LinkedHashMap<String, String> reversed = map.reversed();
```

This reversed view will be a `SequencedMap`.  While it won't be a `LinkedHashMap`, it shares most characteristics with it (e.g. it is mutable, ordered, allows null).

If an `ArrayList` or `LinkedHashMap` are specifically needed, this reversed map can be converted to them in one of the many standard manners of converting a `Map` to one of those types.